# How to rectify "missing right parenthesis" problem?

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is a sample of query I am working on right now:

```sql
CREATE TABLE book (
    book_id       NUMBER(6) NOT NULL CHECK(book_id > 0),
    isbn          VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    title         VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    shelf_letter  VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL CHECK(shelf_letter IN('A-Z')),
    call_number   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL CHECK(call_number IN (1-999)),
    no_of_pages   NUMBER(4),
    no_of_copies  NUMBER(3) NOT NULL CHECK(no_of_copies >= 1),
    date_arrived  DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATE,
    publisher_id  NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    cat_id        NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT shelf_call UNIQUE(shelf_letter,call_number) 
);
```

On compiling, it is throwing a "missing right parenthesis" error. I checked, but all the parentheses are accounted for. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Question (unrelated to the error, and the correct answer you received): If the `shelf_letter` must be a **single** capital letter (between A and Z), why is the column data type `varchar2(2)`, and not `varchar2(1)`? If the shelf "letter" can in fact be two characters, then you must explain in more detail what the allowable values are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual error you are seeing is caused by the `date_arrived` column with `NOT NULL` being placed *before* the default value of `SYSDATE`, when it should be after:

```
date_arrived  DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
```

In addition, the second and third check constraints, while technically valid syntax, look dubious:

```
shelf_letter  VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL CHECK(shelf_letter IN('A-Z')),
call_number   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL CHECK(call_number IN (1-999)),
```

For the check on `shelf_letter`, presumably you want to enforce that it can only be the capital letters from A to Z.  If so, then use `REGEXP_LIKE`:

```
shelf_letter  VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(shelf_letter, '^[A-Z]$')),
```

For the check on `call_number`, use a range comparison:

```
call_number   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL CHECK(call_number BETWEEN 1 AND 999),
```

Putting all this together, use the following create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    book_id       NUMBER(6) NOT NULL CHECK(book_id > 0),
    isbn          VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    title         VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
    shelf_letter  VARCHAR2(2) NOT NULL CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(shelf_letter, '^[A-Z]$')),
    call_number   NUMBER(6) NOT NULL CHECK(call_number BETWEEN 1 AND 999),
    no_of_pages   NUMBER(4),
    no_of_copies  NUMBER(3) NOT NULL CHECK(no_of_copies >= 1),
    date_arrived  DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
    publisher_id  NUMBER(4) NOT NULL,
    cat_id        NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT shelf_call UNIQUE(shelf_letter, call_number)
);
```

### Demo

Comment: Shouldn't cause the error OP is seeing though, right? `IN('A-Z')`, while probably not what OP wants, is syntactically correct (I think)

Comment: Gah, of course. The syntax highlighting threw me off and I thought it was a string.

Comment: The *only* syntactical error is placing the DEFAULT clause after the NOT NULL constraint. `call_number IN (1-999)` is perfectly valid (although obviously not what the OP intended); `-` for numbers is the subtraction operator.

Comment: @mathguy Yes, and I realized this once I setup a demo and found out that my initial "fixes" still left a syntax error.  You are very good at Oracle if you can see this error just by looking at the OP's create statement.

Comment: My comment was addressed specifically to your comment (which you have now deleted), saying that `call_number IN (1-999)` is not valid in Oracle SQL. Other than that, I don't know how good I am at Oracle (perhaps I am good), but yes, I did see that error right away just by looking at the CREATE TABLE statement. I had seen the same error before; and my memory is indeed very good, regardless of how good I am at Oracle.